# Kubernetes autoscaling via api

Tags: api, kubernetes, autoscaling

I want to autoscale my pods based on an api call. i want a scheduler to invoke the api every 5 mins once. Based on the response, considerably with total number of pods to run at the moment will invoke the scaling.

The intention behind is to access a queue service which consumes less CPU and Memory resources, but time as every queue item take a long time to process. so if I horizontally scale pods based on the queue size, the faser the request gets processed. at the moment during peak time, the queue gets overloaded but the scaling wont happen and takes a long time.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can You also add k8s version and which platform You are using?